# how can I assign a range to my int so that i can enter any number and get a different result every time?

Tags: c#

So i am learning C# now, I have tried C++ and Java ( i liked Java more than C++ I still do not fully understand C++) and now i'm giving C# a try. I did another little program that displayed my age, date and time, favorite color, etc, basically it was mostly strings, no int. I want to be able to enter any number in the GrossIncome but be within a range, not just have it set to a specific number,but everything that I could think of to use, visual studio does not like, I have watched some tutorial on pluralsight but none seem to show an example of it.

```
 //My first program 
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace Week1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is my program, enter your name to continue");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + name);


        Console.WriteLine("enter your address");
        string address = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(address);


        Console.WriteLine("enter your monthly income");
        int GrossMonthlyPay = 10000; //here is where i need to have the option to enter any different value like i.e. >0 <10000 
        Console.WriteLine(GrossMonthlyPay);


        Console.WriteLine("your tax deduction set at 7% are ");
        double taxes = (0.07);
        Console.WriteLine(taxes = GrossMonthlyPay * taxes);


        Console.Write("\nPress any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Console.ReadLine()` only gives you a string, so you have to convert it to int yourself. In case the user did not enter integer or it is out of range, you simply reprompt the user for another value.

```
int GetIntBetween(int min, int max) //inclusive
{
    int result;
    string str = Console.ReadLine();
    while (true)
    {
        if (Int32.TryParse(str, out result))
        {
            if (result >= min && result <= max)
                break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Only integer between {0} and {1} (inclusive) is allowed, please reenter another value.", min, max));
        str = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    return result;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither c# nor the .Net framework have a built in type for range.
There are several options, though:

- Use a [`Tuple`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx) (and in c# 7.0 or higher, [`ValueTuple`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/26/c-7-series-part-1-value-tuples/))
- Create an immutable [struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/struct) with the int properties for From and To
- Create your own [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/class) with int properties for From and To
- Use an array with 2 int values
- Use an [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types)

I would recommend using a `ValueTuple` if you are working with c# 7.0 or higher.
If you are working with a lower version of c#, I would recommend creating an immutable struct. I would not recommend using any collection type (e.g array, list etc') nor would I recommend using a `Tuple` or an anonymous type.
It all boils down to code readability. If you are using value tuples or creating your own type, you can set the names of the properties.
With `System.Tuple` you can only use the built in `Item1` and `Item2` which clutters your code.

For c# 6, I would probably create a struct to represent a range:
(for lower versions of c# you need to change a few things such as the usage of string interpolation and getters only auto-implemented properties, but still an immutable struct is probably the best option)

```
public struct Range
{
    public Range(int from, int to)
        : this()
    {
        From = from;
        To = to;
    }
    public int From { get; }
    public int To { get; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{From} - {To}";
    }
}
```

And you can create it with a console application like this:

```
public static void Main()
{

    Console.WriteLine("Enter salary range:");
    var low = GetIntFromUser("From:", "value must be an integer");
    var high = GetIntFromUser("To:", "value must be an integer");
    var range = new Range(low, high);
    Console.WriteLine("Salary entered is {0}", range);
}

public static int GetIntFromUser(string askFor, string error)
{
    int result = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(askFor);
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        if(int.TryParse(input, out result))
        {
            return result;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(error);
    }
}
```

[See a live demo on DotNetFiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xDQano)

Comment: would a list work for this?

Comment: A list is a collection. It's not designed to describe a range, but to hold multiple instances of a specific type.

Comment: @ZoharPeled In ASP.NET MVC DataAnnotation can be used for range, Does Console have anything like that?

Comment: @Adrian Not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Console.ReadLine() will return string, So when you need to convert string to int when you need to judge the GrossMonthlyPay.

```
int n;
if ( int.TryParse(GrossMonthlyPay, out n) )
{
    // n is int, can judge here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't in the console. You can just tell the user to reenter a valid loan number, if the last one was out of range. What you want can be done with an UI. There you can restrict the valid numbers. Just need to listen to value changes and than adjust accordingly.

Comment: right, i was not talking about the console, i was referring to writing it in my code in Visual Studio. I tried typing something like (1, 1000) but gave me an error, i just dont know what is the proper way to do this.

Comment: 1,100 is not a valid number in C#, You can remove all the comma and then It can be parsed in c#